# Behavior of fgets with stdin not blocking with cout

Tags: c++, fgets

Behavior of `fgets`, when used with `stdin`, is not blocking with `cout`.

```
/* Understanding fgets behaviour */

#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char A[20], B[100];

    cin>>A;
    cout<<strlen(A)<<" = Length of A\n";

    // In this case programme stops for taking input for B 

    //cin>>B;
    //cout<<strlen(B)<<" = Length of B\n";

    /* But in this case , programme will 
     * not stop for taking input for B and 
     * exit with below output.(Mentioned end of the programme.) 
     */

    fgets(B,100,stdin);
    cout<<strlen(B)<<" = Length of B\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
input:
asdf

output:
4 = Length of A
1 = Length of B
```

Comment: Why are you mixing C with C++? Why use a `char` array when you can use a `string`? Why use `fgets` at all?

Comment: you typed asdf<enter>. cin>>A reads asdf. fgets reads <enter>.

Comment: At least don't use `cin` and `fgets` at the same time...